# Why is the sum of cosines of angles defining a point

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, 3d

Consider a point P in 3D space which makes an angle $\alpha$ to the $x$-axis an angle $\beta$ to the $y$-axis and an angle $\gamma$ to the $z$-axis. The sum of the squares of the cosines of these angles will equal 1: $\cos^2 \alpha + \cos^2 \beta + \cos^2 \gamma = 1$. Why is this?

Comment: "*Consider a point $P$ in 3D space which makes an angle ...*" $\;$ Points do not make angles. You must mean the position vector of $P$.

Comment: That's simply repeating the equation physBa is asking about!

Comment: @GeorgeIvey: The link provided in the comment of dxiv contains an answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Let's define a vector $\vec{v} = (x,y,z)$

$$\cos^2 \alpha + \cos^2 \beta + \cos^2 \gamma = 1$$
$$\left({x\over |\vec{v}|}\right)^2 + \left({y\over |\vec{v}|}\right)^2 + \left({z\over |\vec{v}|}\right)^2 = 1$$

$$\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{|\vec{v}|^2}=1$$
And you got the pythagoras theorem
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=|\vec{v}|^2$$